flutter_local_notification Foreground notification listen (like FCM onMessage.listen)
I'm working with local notifications in a Flutter app and want to achieve the following behavior:

When the app is in the background and a scheduled notification
arrives, I want the notification to be displayed as usual by the
system.

However, if the user is in the
foreground, I want to show a custom dialog instead of the default
notification behavior.



Hello, I have the same issue. I cannot handle the message with local notification. Did you resolve?

Nope, I guess there is no way to listen them. Checkout awesome_notifications package, this has listeners.

How can you listen the background or terminated display event with awesome_notifications?
